# apache webserver access from internet

Tags: networking, apache2, iptables

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed in VMWARE running my website in apache2

I tried with IPTables but no luck.  Port 80,443 is open in UFW firewall status.  I have public IP which has the ISP running their own website wherein I can ping from my local host to the vmware IP 192.168.1.143.

I can ping from vmware to host computer. I can access the website using the IP address mentioned above from host.

I need to access the website using the domain name.  I need a firewall rule to port forward 80 to some other IP to listen from my public IP to the vmware IP to access the website.

Comment: Are you using any router? If so, you should forward port 80 to the local IP of your virtual machine in your router settings. You should also use bridge as network setting for your virtual machine, so it will get IP directly from the router

Comment: I had configured the VMWARE as bridged network i made the listen port apache to 8080. I have a wireless point with public ip and a static ip for the wan.  I have the dhcp configured ip to my vmware.  I am not aware of the iptables to how to accept connections from my host or internet to forward traffic to apache ubuntu.

Comment: So you need your router to forward port 80 requests to your vmware computer at 192.168.1.143 port 8080. You do not need any iptables rules in your host for this.

Comment: Please let me know is this  correct
https://ibb.co/ja030k